# How to set value for the checkbox in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I try to show my value using checkbox. Value always comes for the console log. But it didn't set for the checkbox. Here is the code and image for my problem:

```
     var NotePage = createClass({
 

      addTags(e) {
        console.log("id****************", e.target.id);
        let id = e.target.id;
        let selectedTags = this.state.selectedTags;
        if (selectedTags.includes(id)) {
          var index = selectedTags.indexOf(id)
          selectedTags.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          selectedTags.push(id);
        }
        console.log("id****************selectedTags", selectedTags);

        this.setState({
          selectedTags: selectedTags
        })

       },







     render: function () {
       assignStates: function (note, token, tagCategories) {
   
           let fields = [];
           fields["title"] = note.title_en;
           fields["body"] = note.body_en;
           let selectedFileName = null
   
           if (note.file_url_en != "") {
             console.log("note.file_url_en ", note.file_url_en);
             selectedFileName = note.file_url_en
   
           }
           let selectedTags = [];
           let n = 0;
           (note.note_tag).forEach(tag => {
             selectedTags.push(tag.id.toString());
             n++;
           });
   
           console.log("id****************first", selectedTags);
   
           let initial_values = {
             note: note,
             id: note.id,
             api: new Api(token),
             message: "",
             title: note.title_en,
             body: note.body_en,
             fields: fields,
             isEdit: false,
             selectedTags: selectedTags,
             tagCategories: tagCategories,
             selectedFileName: selectedFileName,
           }
           return initial_values;
       },
   
       const { selectedTags } = this.state;
             {(tagCategory.tags).map((tag) => (
                           <div className="col-3">
                             <div>
                               <input
                                 type="checkbox"
                                 value={selectedTags.includes(tag.id)}
                                 id={tag.id}
                                 onChange={this.addTags} />
                               <label style={{ marginLeft: "10px", fontSize: "15px" }}>
                                 {tag.name_en}
                               </label>
                             </div>
                           </div>
              ))
      }
   })
```

[Image related for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYpR5.png)

Comment: Where is your `addTags` function?

Comment: Sorry I will added it.

Comment: @Sinan Yaman can you please check it now

Answer (score 2):

You've an issue with state mutation. You save a reference to the current state, mutate it, and then save it back into state. This breaks React's use of shallow reference equality checks during reconciliation to determine what needs to be flushed to the DOM.

```
addTags(e) {
  let id = e.target.id;

  let selectedTags = this.state.selectedTags; // reference to state

  if (selectedTags.includes(id)) {
    var index = selectedTags.indexOf(id)
    selectedTags.splice(index, 1); // mutation!!
  } else {
    selectedTags.push(id); // mutation!!
  }

  this.setState({
    selectedTags: selectedTags // same reference as previous state
  });
},
```

To remedy you necessarily return a new array object reference.

```
addTags(e) {
  const { id } = e.target;

  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (prevState.selectedTags.includes(id)) {
      return {
        selectedTags: prevState.selectedTags.filter(el => el !== id),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        selectedTags: prevState.selectedTags.concat(id),
      };
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "checked" attribute.

```
                         <input
                          type="checkbox"

                          value={tag.id}
                          checked={selectedTags.includes(tag.id)}
                          id={tag.id}

                          onChange={this.addTags} />
```

also, about the value attribute in checkboxes:

> A DOMString representing the value of the checkbox. This is not displayed on the client-side, but on the server this is the value given to the data submitted with the checkbox's name.
>
> Note: If a checkbox is unchecked when its form is submitted, there is
> no value submitted to the server to represent its unchecked state
> (e.g. value=unchecked); the value is not submitted to the server at
> all. If you wanted to submit a default value for the checkbox when it
> is unchecked, you could include an  inside the
> form with the same name and value, generated by JavaScript perhaps.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use checked property instead of value.

For reference check react js docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating state variable directly with `selectedTags.splice(index, 1);` and `selectedTags.push(id);`

What you need to do is make a copy of the state variable and change that:

```
      addTags(e) {
        let id = e.target.id;
        if (this.state.selectedTags.includes(id)) {
          this.setState(state => (
            {...state, selectedTags: state.selectedTags.filter(tag => tag !== id)}
          ))
        } else {
          this.setState(state => (
            {...state, selectedTags: [...state.selectedTags, id]}
          ))
        }
       }
```

Comment: This is your code, you can replace your `addTags` function with this. Or, if you can create a `codesandbox` example, I will make it work. Either this or @DrewReese 's solution should work. Do you get an error?

Comment: no errors coming but the checkbox still not ticking

Comment: You also need to use  `checked = {selectedTags.includes(tag.id)}` instead of value, as others mentioned.

Comment: yes I used with that part but it did't work

Comment: Then problem should be somewhere else, can you create a `codesandbox`?